# Physical address of the address returned by kmalloc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory-address, virtual-memory, kmalloc

I'm a bit confused about the addresses that kmalloc is returning to me. According to [the virtual memory map](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt), the addresses I'm getting are in the `ffff880000000000` - `ffffc7ffffffffff` range, so the "direct mapping of all phys. memory". How does this mapping work? I'm pretty certain that kmalloc doesn't simply return a physical address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `kmalloc` is returning a virtual address, not a physical one. The memory map you linked to is describing the *virtual* memory map, not the *physical* memory map.

A virtual address typically is translated to a physical address by the MMU when you access data at the address. What the virtual address translates to depends on the memory map specified by the kernel.

The memory map you linked to shows how Linux does the mapping. It is saying, if you have a virtual address between `0xffff880000000000`  and `0xffffc7ffffffffff`, it is mapped to somewhere in physical memory (we don't know where exactly nor do we care unless we're doing DMA).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, great answer! How does this relate to addresses returned by vmalloc? I noticed that these addresses look different. From the virtual memory map I posted above tey would be in the vmalloc pool. Are these virtual addresses as well that are mapped to physical addresses like the ones from kmalloc or could the scheme possibly be different...or perhaps a physical address doesn't always exist and the page might get swapped out? My intuition might be wrong, but would it make sense to swap out kernel data pages?

Comment: Those virtual addresses are most likely mapped to the physical memory.

Comment: okay, so if I allocate some memory with kmalloc or vmalloc in some LKM, any other LKM could access this memory as well by using the same addresses?

Comment: @tangrs How to find that physical memoy. I am using `virt_to_phys()` in ubuntu 64 bit 4.4.x kernel and I am not getting the correct value. Basically I am getting the offset part of the virtual address.