Can a kernel memory address indicate its type of allocation?
I'm troubleshooting some Linux kernel code, and it would be nice to know where the memory pointer allocation originated.
Question: Are there Linux kernel macros available like ADDR_IS_STACK_ADDR(ptr) or ADDR_IS_HEAP_ADDR(ptr) so I can check where an addr might have come from?  If so, please point me in the right direction
In my case I just want to know if it is from a stack variable passed by reference... but it might be nice to know if there are macros to check:

is the address from the stack?
is the address from the kmalloc?
is the address from the vmalloc?
from .text , like a function pointer?
other classifications?

For example:
void foo()
{
  int bar;
  void *v = vmalloc(123);
  void *k = kmalloc(123);
  if (ADDR_IS_STACK_ADDR(&bar))
     pr_debug("%p is on the stack\n", &bar);
  else if (ADDR_IS_HEAP_ADDR(k))
     pr_debug("%p is on the heap\n", k);
  else if (ADDR_IS_VIRT_ADDR(v))
     pr_debug("%p is virtual and maps to physical addr %p\n", 
        v, virt_to_phys(v));
}


"For example: ... else if (ADDR_IS_VIRT_ADDR(v)) ..." - Nice to actually see someone use kernel coding style. But your example seems hastily written because the conditional logic makes little sense. Practically every address is a virtual address. To single out the address for a dynamic allocation from vmalloc() as a "virtual address" seems like a sloppy description.

There are possibilities to recognize constant addresses (see kfree_const() impl), k/v allocated addresses (see kvfree() impl). There are might be others, but I am not concerned about them.

And side note, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907254/why-the-out-of-p-and-x-is-different-in-linux-driver/74912749#74912749.

@sawdust, interesting: I always thought kmalloc provided physical addr's, but I guess that isn't the case.  Maybe it used to be, or maybe I'm just mistaken?  Anyway, thanks for pointing that out.  Ultimately I want to know if something was passed down by reference on the stack, whether or not it is virtual, thus virt is last in the example.

TL;DR: there is no real robust way to tell. You can make an educated guess, but there are going to be exceptions. For example, kernel text is mapped twice in kernel virtual memory, as well as kernel data/rodata. kmalloc() and friends return addresses in the linear mapping, but other things can live there too. There are also addresses that do not make sense whatsoever for kernel code to use like bus/io addresses. The real answer here is that whatever code you are writing that needs to know this information should probably be rewritten.

"I always thought kmalloc provided physical addr's" - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250934/physical-address-of-the-address-returned-by-kmalloc

Thanks @sawdust.  Here is another see-also for future readers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc
